# Why are the thumbnails for PPTX not working in MS Graph Search

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using the Microsoft Graph explorer to search for PPTX files inside Sharepoint:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MYSITE.sharepoint.com/drive/root/search(q = 'term AND .pptx')?$expand=thumbnails`

This works fine and returns results including urls for thumbnails, for example:

```
    "value": [
        {
         [...],
        "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "large": {
                        "height": 800,
                        "url": "https://westeurope1-mediap.svc.ms/transform/thumbnail?provider=spo&inputFormat=pptx&cs=ZGU4YmM4YjUtZDlmOS00OGIxLWE4YWQtYjc0OGRhNzI1MDY0fFNQTw&docid=https%3A%2F%2Fveodin2%2Esharepoint%2Ecom%2F%5Fapi%2Fv2%2E0%2Fdrives%2Fb%21ZZLBnC7JSUiDFsO07HLwwZiU%5F3PZL3hOreOxO%2D7%2D6OUVoo3IebmnSLCtR%5FGar3MR%2Fitems%2F01D33FTF2VJGLOTD3PG5HJEJTWDA5HQN4T%3Faccess%5Ftoken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9%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%2EZ%2D3mJ6UrcrCyvXB0fOJpZgArYqHAShQDVhSb6XaoJY4%26prooftoken%3DeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6InhYbFQwSUp4MlZCVEJFeVFMdGtFOFY2ZkhwZyJ9%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%2EpHVBmvjFcARCcygYv4ll6zuayGQRDChsHI7%5FNSEic%5F0U8PB9mmrIqE2cw%5FlNLKxVQ0pLlbV%2Dx64K6SlxwC1jSRzUNlsEAuEdMKNxlnKVND81OZoGYFMm3vMjHnFmXXIrv7CRc93NeFcByYwU%2DnqHg%2D2ETvyaUmdQjqdoBXtCVo80Jybj0Tek3f8qnz%2DncexDzAks6nBlgjhEqRi9hTBPWblnhvDZVoeQYb26MCU2pwyhWRe3ziH6M4WuEqT4NaOU9v3UNtK87rG%5Ffg%2DL5DVbWlYb2vywt1jNKFYs535WPHAFOS7h3ior4qHP471xTr4s%5Frgu1%2Dz0o0Ep9S%2DZXaj5kw%26version%3DPublished&width=800&height=800&cb=63627410891",
                        "width": 800
                    },
                    [...]
            }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However the URL returned doesn't work but throws an error:

```
{"error":{

  "code": "generalException",

  "message": "Error from Office Service. Url=https://pptcs.officeapps.live.com/document/export/thumbnail HttpCode=NotFound cert=subject:;thumbprint: ResponseHeaders=Connection: close\r\nDate: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 12:25:31 GMT\r\nServer: Microsoft-IIS/10.0\r\nX-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n",

  "innererror": {

    "code": "OfficeConversion_ConverterInternal"

  }

}}
```

It works fine with PDFs.

Also querying explicitly for the thumbnail urls (after searching for the item ids) works like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/MYSITE.sharepoint.com/drive/items/{item-id}/thumbnails

Comment: You can use the Item id of the pptx file and use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45/drives/b!loMXwUXY-ka8DEU9KVHa1R6a7hkdAPFInuiwrf3lTkWmzNPKD2ILQLNdmX03mXTy/Items/01LPJ34YWUHZYHVWNCDNAYCRCLHNNDSAII?$expand=thumbnails` Replace siteid,driveid if required and ItemId after getting the item and use this call. It worked for me. Give it a try.

Comment: Did the call work for you?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity Thanks for confirming that direct query of the thumbnails works. Like I've written in my question.

However I'd like to avoid the explict calling for thumbnails and have them included in the original search query.

Including them works fine and the urls are returned. But calling the urls is failing.